# Array index out of bounds with JSwing and 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to create a program that stores student test scores.

Each student has 4 test scores that must be stored in a 2D array. The JSwing App will allow users to enter 4 test marks and once they click a button it will add the 4 marks to the array.

I have tried to figure out how to do it by I keep getting arrayindexboundexception. Also, I am not sure if I am even doing it correctly.

This is all done in `JSwing` by the way.

```
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {
    final static int students = 15;
    final static int numOfTest = 4;

    //DELCARING THE 2D ARRAY
    double[][] marks = new double[students][numOfTest];

    public void addInfo() {
        double testScores[] = new double[4];
        String test1, test2, test3, test4;
        double score1, score2, score3, score4;
        int i = 0;
        test1 = testOneIn.getText();
        test2 = testTwoIn.getText();
        test3 = testThreeIn.getText();
        test4 = testFourIn.getText();
        score1 = Double.parseDouble(test1);
        score2 = Double.parseDouble(test2);
        score3 = Double.parseDouble(test3);
        score4 = Double.parseDouble(test4);
        testScores[0] = score1;
        testScores[1] = score2;
        testScores[2] = score3;
        testScores[3] = score4;

        //First for loop starts at in the first row and automatically
        //increments to the next row after the first rows columns are filled
        for (int row = 0; row < marks.length; row++) {

            //Second loop automatically cycles through each column in the
            //current row adding test scores. After this loop finishes
            //the program returns to the first loop and advances to the next 
            //row, at which point it will fill that row with the same test data.
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                marks[row][col] = testScores[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops?

Comment: 2 loops because one for the row and one for the collumn.

The first student will have 4 test marks
and then the second will have 4 test marks

Comment: Yeah, OP is right - a 2d array is appropriate (rows = students, columns = tests) and thus so is using two loops to fill it. The big issue here - and I'm assuming this is a typo made in c/p this code onto here - where is your `marks` array created?

Comment: What is "JSwing"? I'm not familiar with this beast.

Comment: @drewmore That's exactly why I was confused as to why 2 loops - I can't see a `marks` array anywhere.

Comment: @shree.pat18 yeah, OP hasn't posted that part of the code, and I suspect that's where the AIOB is being thrown

Comment: oh shoot. Ill add it in right now sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I should be adding a second answer, but this is how it should look

```
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {
 final static int students=15;
 final static int numOfTest=4;

 //Start with the first student in the 2D array
 private int row = 0;


//DELCARING THE 2D ARRAY
double[][] marks = new double[students][numOfTest];


public void addInfo(){
    double testScores[]=new double[4];
    testScores[0]=Double.parseDouble(testOneIn.getText());
    testScores[1]=Double.parseDouble(testTwoIn.getText());
    testScores[2]=Double.parseDouble(testThreeIn.getText());
    testScores[3]=Double.parseDouble(testFourIn.getText());

    //Add all four test scores to the current student
        for(int col=0;col < testScores.length; col++){
            marks[row][col]= testScores[col];
            }

    //Advance to the next student
    row++;
   }
  }
```

Comment: I edited this again. I just realized you didn't even need the `int i` to track the testScores array index.

Answer (score 2):

For your original problem

```
for(int row=0; row <marks.length; row++){
        for(int col=0;col <4; col++){
            marks[row][col]= testScores[i];
            i++;
        }
```

Is incrementing i beyond the length of testScores. Use this

```
for(int row=0; row <marks.length; row++){
            i = 0;
            for(int col=0;col <4; col++){
                marks[row][col]= testScores[i];
                i++;
         }
```

FWIW, you can also reduce the amount of code you have in this section, the number of variables, and ultimately the amount of memory allocated for variables:

```
    test1=testOneIn.getText();
    test2=testTwoIn.getText();
    test3=testThreeIn.getText();
    test4=testFourIn.getText();
    score1=Double.parseDouble(test1);
    score2=Double.parseDouble(test2);
    score3=Double.parseDouble(test3);
    score4=Double.parseDouble(test4);
    testScores[0]=score1;
    testScores[1]=score2;
    testScores[2]=score3;
    testScores[3]=score4;
```

by doing something like this

```
    testScores[0] = Double.parseDouble(testOneIn.getText());
```

Comment: I need 15 rep for that. New member here lmao!

Comment: Good point. I think you should still be able to select your answer by clicking the check for the one that solved your original problem (not mine as it was an offshoot).

Comment: actually, it looks like no one answered it. Recheck this answer in a minute

Comment: Looks good but I have another question to add ontop of it.

Do I need another array to hold each of the students information? Because if they click to add another students set of test marks would it not overwrite the previous students information?

Comment: @Traplord I believe my answer deals with the problem of overwrite.

Comment: Actually, the way you have it now, all 15 students are going to be given the same test scores. If the submit button is clicked again, it will overwrite all 15 students with the new test scores. If the scores are going to be added for each student in succession, you only need the inner `for` loop, and increment marks[row] by one every time `addInfo()` is called

Comment: In that case, row will also have to be a private class variable.

Comment: @NonSecwitter I like the suggestion of row count as a member variable better than adding student number to the form like I suggested.

Comment: I think it depends on what he is trying to do. I like your version too. It was actually my first thought. I guess it just depends on whether he needs to manage each student, or just load in test scores in order.

Comment: So to rephrase what I was trying to say above is.

Program must handle atleast 15 students. So I just put 15.
Each student has 4 test scores.

If I hit the add button then it adds the 4 test scores to that particular student.

If i click add again it adds a new student with new marks

and so on

Comment: Yea, the problem is that your double `for` loop is cycling through the entire 2D array with a single set of test scores. You either need to select each student individually as @JeffWard suggested, or increment through them automatically as I suggested. Or, maybe there is another solution, but those two work.

Comment: Hmm. Could I use their name to keep the data?

Cause I also need the user to input their name (first and last) into 2 different inputs therefore that means using a 2d array.

Comment: If you can associate the name with the index number somehow. @JeffWard might have a better answer for that. My first thought is a 3D array or storing everything in a String array and having the 0 index be the name.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `i` beyond the bounds of your `testScores` array. The array only has a length of 4. The second iteration of `marks` would cause `i > testScores.length` giving you the exception.

Consider updating your input to accept the student number:

```
int student = Integer.parseInt(studentIn.getText());
```

Then you could apply the test score input to that student only:

```
for (int col = 0, i = 0; col < 4; col++, i++) {
    marks[student][col] = testScores[i]; 
}
```

Also since you are not doing a double for loop the `i` variable isn't necessary you could use `col` instead:

```
for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
    marks[student][col] = testScores[col]; 
}
```